# My app cannot work when I installed ember-cli-cordova, I need some advises

Tags: cordova, ember.js

I installed ember-cli-cordova following ember-cli-cordova's **Getting Started** guidance.

**Step 01:**

> npm install -g ember-cli
>
> npm install -g cordova

**Step 02:**

> ember new project-name

**Step 03:** You have to run ember commands in the project directory.

> cd project-name

**Step 04:** Create "dist" directory.

> ember build

**Step 05:**

> ember install ember-cli-cordova

**Step 06:** edit config/environment.js

1) change "locationType: 'auto'" to "locationType: 'hash'".
      (cordova needs hash as locationType)

2) Add setting "Env.cordova...."

**Step 07:**

> ember generate cordova-init com.rabit.hybrid

**Step 08:** Edit config/environment.js

```
defaultLocationType: 'hash',
...
cordova: {
...
    platform: 'android',
```

**Step 09:**

> ember generate cordova-starter-kit

**Step 10:**

> C:\MyWorkSpace\Dvlp\Trial\hybridOne>ember server
>
> version: 1.13.13
>
> Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
>
> Serving on http://localhost:4200/
>
> ***ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\MyWorkSpace\Dvlp\Trial\hybridOne\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-EtFoLMHC.tmp\0\bower_components\hammerjs\hammer.js'***
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\MyWorkSpace\Dvlp\Trial\hybridOne\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-EtFoLMHC.tmp\0\bower_components\hammerjs\hammer.js'
>
> at Error (native)
>
> at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
>
> at ConcatWithMaps.keyForFile (C:\MyWorkSpace\Dvlp\Trial\hybridOne\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-sourcemap-concat\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:90:20)

Hope someone can tell me what's wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try step 4 after configuring all settings.

Comment: Thank your answer. I'll try it now.

Comment: WARNs and 1 ERR! occured when I ran "npm install -g ember-cl".
So I uninstall node.js and delete the directories, npm and npm-cashe under AppData/Roaming.
Then I reinstalled node.js and ran "npm install -g ember-cl" again.
It succeded this time.
"npm install -g cordova" takes long time.....still installing

Comment: Before Step 09, 'ember serve' worked well.
But after Step 10, 

'ember serve' could not work with the following error message: 

"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\MyWorkSpace\Dvlp\Trial\hybridOne\tmp\concat_with_maps-input_base_path-EtFoLMHC.tmp\0\bower_components\hammerjs\hammer.js'".

Then, I ran a command 'bower install hammerjs --save', 
and tried to run 'ember serve' again, the error disappeared and 
I got "Welcome to ember-cli-cordova!" on my browser.

I think the problem should exist in 'ember generate cordova-starter-kit'.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `bower_components` directory might be corrupted. You should try removing completely `bower_components` and then `bower install`.

Comment: Thank your answer, I'll try it now.